# Azure Bot Service, downloading code not from scratch

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I suffer from long response time via Microsoft Bot Framework in FB Messenger, tried to google around - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1395
people are having same issues, but there was one interesting [answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1395#issuecomment-272690440). 
For now, I have it deployed as App Service, with messaging endpoint as API.
At this point, I started thinking about redeploying my bot as Azure Bot Service because of performance.

Do I have a possibility to deploy my pre-made via MBF chat-bot as Azure Bot Service? 
What Azure show's me when I create Bot Service:
[image]

I don't want to create a new app! And as far as I know, there is no opportunity to edit bot code in Visual Studio if you have it hosted as Bot Service. Is it right?

Comment: The post linked is talking about performance when using Direct Line. Are you using Direct Line?

Comment: I am using Slack and Facebook Messenger, response is slow there also.